# Running programs on another computer in C

Tags: c, system, running-other-programs

I am making an FTP in C for learning purposes. I know how to connect to a computer and read/write a file, but I'm having problems with running programs. My idea is to connect to the computer, cd into a directory called Available and run `ls -l` or `dir` depending on what type of operating system the computer the client has connected to has. After I run one of the commands I want to be able to list the results on the client's computer. My question is, is this possible and if so what would I do? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2):

Don't run console commands like that. Use the operating system's API / system calls to enumerate files in the current directory.

Windows: FindFirst/FindNextFile APIs
Linux: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node20.html#SECTION002000000000000000000 <-- this should help for linux

Comment: Will this display the other computer's files on the client's computer or what specifically will it do?

Comment: Enumerate the files. Send it back through a socket to the other computer. Display the information in whatever manner you wish.